# Overflow encountered in matmul while doing forward propagation

Tags: neural-network, numpy

I wrote this code to do forward propagation

```py
def forward_prop(w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3, X):
    z1 = np.matmul(w1, X) + b1
    a1 = ReLU(z1)

    z2 = np.matmul(w2, a1) + b2
    a2 = ReLU(z2)

    z3 = np.matmul(w3, a2) + b3
    a3 = softmax(z3)

    return z1, a1, z2, a2, z3, a3
```

and I noticed that the weights are all nan after the learning completes, after debugging I saw that the reason is that there is an inf in the z1 after the execution of this function. also it shows the warning "overflow encountered in matmul".

I am initializing my weights and biases like this

```py
def init_params():
    w1 = np.random.rand(256, 784) - 0.2
    b1 = np.random.rand(256, 1) - 0.2

    w2 = np.random.rand(128, 256) - 0.2
    b2 = np.random.rand(128, 1) - 0.2

    w3 = np.random.rand(10, 128) - 0.2
    b3 = np.random.rand(10, 1) - 0.2

    return w1, b1, w2, b2, w3, b3
```

and X is the training set for MNIST dataset.
I also tried feature scaling on the training set but it didn't work
What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: You're hoping to get activation values on the unit interval, right? Or in [-1 .. 1] ? Yet the weights seem to be up in the hundreds? I can't imagine how that would work. Go look at a working MNIST model, perhaps in keras or pytorch, and view histograms of the weight values. Then ask yourself how that model achieved stability & convergence, and how its training mechanism differs from the one you outline above.